# Django view.py call shell-script that include another python script

Tags: python, django, linux, shell, django-views

i use `os.system` or `commands.getstatusout` function， the arg is a cmd  `(cmd="sh /path/to/a.sh argv1 argv2")`

```
a.sh
#something one
python /path/to/b.py argv1 argv2
#something else
```

when i put `os.system(cmd)` to Django's view, log showed error！such as  `could not found module "XXX"(b.py) ,XXX is not Django's some function`, like orderdict ,tornado...

but i have install them with pip

then ,i write a standlone python script (`include os.system(cmd)`),and it's run success!

idon't know why！

PS：i tryed add `sys.path.append(...)` to `b.py`  or add `source /etc/profile` ... to `a.sh`,but still failed!

Comment: about pip install if you use virtualenv you should type "source bin/activate" first from your virtualenv. Same for you `python /path/to/whatever` which will permit to locate the python binary AND will set environment variable to your django app